# Is there a way to use a generic type without explicit typing?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a generic type, where a generic parameter type is inferred from one of the properties of the type. A simplified scenario:

```js
// with this setup
const permissionGroups = {
  users: ['read'],
  scripts: ['execute'],
} as const;
type PermissionGroups = typeof permissionGroups;



// this would be nice, but does not work
type PermissionToCheck = <T extends keyof PermissionGroups>{
  group: T;
  permission: PermissionGroups[T][number];
};

function checkPermission(permissionToCheck: PermissionToCheck) {}


// this does, but is inconvenient
type PermissionToCheck<T extends keyof PermissionGroups> = {
  group: T;
  permission: PermissionGroups[T][number];
};

function checkPermission<T extends keyof PermissionGroups>( // repeated generic constraint
  permissionToCheck: PermissionToCheck<T>,
) {}
```

I'm comparing this to similar pattern for functions, where generic type argument can be inferred from the usage:

```js
type SomeCallback = <T>(arg: T[]) => T;

function doStuff(callback: SomeCallback) {
  const result = callback([1,2]);  // result is number, no need for explicit type anywhere
}
```

Is there any way to avoid passing generic parameter every time I use `PermissionToCheck` type and still have a proper type checking?

Comment: You *might* be asking for [generic value types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) but it sounds you don't really want such behavior (or else `checkPermission(permissionToCheck)` would require `permissionToCheck` to represent *every* possible permission, not just *some* permission).  The `SomeCallback` type isn't just a different way of writing `type SpecificCallback<T> = (arg: T[])=>T`; it has different behavior.  If you're just looking a more convenient notation for `PermissionToCheck<T>`, I don't think any exists.

Comment: @jcalz You're exactly on point with generic value types as evidenced by comments like this one - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574#issuecomment-486461565 which basically describes my use case. I can see that it's not possible just yet but now I have an issue to follow. Thanks.